# Firemonkey custom control click events firing in designer

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I have a custom Firemonkey control that has several sub components.  These sub components have OnClick events associated with them that are setup in the control's constructor. I have noticed that when I click on the custom control in my design view, the OnClick events of these sub components are getting fired.

Is there a particular setting or best practice I need to employ to prevent this from happening?

Is there something I can check in my C++ code to see if this event is being run in the designer vs at run time? Something like:

```
void __fastcall MyControlOnClick( TObject * Sender )
{
    if( InDesigner == false )
    {
         //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ComponentState`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.ComponentState) property.  It has a `csDesigning` flag enabled when your control is being used in the Form Designer.

```
void __fastcall MyControl::SubControlClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    if( !ComponentState.Contains(csDesigning) )
    {
         //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, simply don't assign the `OnClick` handlers at design-time to begin with:

```
__fastcall MyControl::MyControl(TComponent *Owner)
    : TBaseControl(Owner)
{
    ...
    FSubControl = new TWhatever(this);
    if( !ComponentState.Contains(csDesigning) )
        FSubControl->OnClick = &SubControlClick;
    ...
}
```